# Add column with numbers corresponding to how many times a value in another column is seen

Tags: r, dataframe, tidy

I have a large dataframe that I have subset to simplify my question, it looks like this:

```
genome_ID     cluster  
p1.A2           1        
p1.A2           3         
p1.A2           3          
p1.A2           4          
p1.A3           2          
p1.A4           2          
p1.A5           1          
p1.A5           3
```

And I would like to add a column 'phages' to the dataframe and add numbers corresponding to how many times the genome_ID is present... ie..

```
  genome_ID     cluster     phages
    p1.A2           1         1
    p1.A2           3         2
    p1.A2           3         3
    p1.A2           4         4
    p1.A3           2         1 
    p1.A4           2         1
    p1.A5           1         1
    p1.A5           3         2
```

So as you can see the genome_ID p1.A2 is present four times, so there are now four different groupings in the column phages (1-4).  p1.A5 is present twice, so there is now numbering from 1-2.  If a genome_ID were present fifty times, I would like the column phages to number each from 1-50 (and the order of numbering doesn't matter)

I need to do this so I can subset my dataset more easily to map it to a phylogeny (a biological tree showing evolutionary relationships)

If someone could give me insight to useful R packages and methods that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(genome_ID) %>% mutate(phages = row_number())
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   genome_ID [4]
  genome_ID cluster phages
  <chr>       <dbl>  <int>
1 p1.A2           1      1
2 p1.A2           3      2
3 p1.A2           3      3
4 p1.A2           4      4
5 p1.A3           2      1
6 p1.A4           2      1
7 p1.A5           1      1
8 p1.A5           3      2
```

Comment: For some reason when I re-started my environment it is no longer working and is giving me this error: Error: `n()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs.  Do you have any idea of why this is happening?

Comment: I fixed it by adding dplyrr:: in front of mutate